# Por que os navegadores acham que “esquadraoclasseA” é uma cor?

Tags: html, navegador-de-internet

Por exemplo, `bgcolor="esquadraoclasseA"` produz um fundo vermelho:

```html
<body bgcolor="esquadraoclasseA"> teste esquadraoclasseA </body>
```

Por outro lado, `bgcolor="BR"` produz um fundo negro:

```html
<body bgcolor="BR"> teste BR </body>
```

Bem sei que o atributo `bgcolor` está depreciado desde o HTML5 a favor do atributo `style=”background:;”`, o qual, corretamente, não reconhece nem `“esquadraoclasseA”`, nem `“BR”` como cores, pois não constam em nenhuma especificação W3C e nem sequer estão implementadas de forma não standard em qualquer navegador antigo ou atual.

Existe alguma explicação lógica para o atributo depreciado `bgcolor` tentar interpretar tais cores? Isso é válido para várias plataformas e navegadores. Porquê?